# Disable function calls or disable code's lines C++ in logging

Tags: c++, logging, heap-memory, valgrind, allocation

Is there an existing way to disable every code's lines of a logger depends on log_level without surrounding every call by an `ifndef` ?

```
// 5 debug
// 4 info
// 3 warning
// 2 error
// 1 fatal
```

My problem is that even with a log_level set to 3 for exemple, only the warning logger and less will be printed obviously, but the rvalue arguments of every function of my logger are consuming time, Exemple :

`Globals::LOGGER.logger_DEBUG("MyFunction", "rvalue is " + std::to_string(8));`

Even with a `log_level = 3`, this function will be called, will print nothing, but will create 2 temporary strings and assigns bytes.

My target is to disable every `Globals::LOGGER.logger_xxxx` line depends on the log_level

My logger definition :

logger.hpp :

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

/**
 * Class used to make logs
*/
class Logger
{
private:

int _Log_level;

public:
/**
 * Contructor
 * @param Log_level Level of log we want to print
 * @param Name_Log_File Name of the log.txt
*/
Logger(int pLog_level = 4, const std::string &pName_Log_File = "cmd");

/**
 * Destructor
*/
~Logger();

/**
 * Logger printed when the Log_level is 5
 * @param Class_function String that represent the class::function
 * @param Message String that we want to print
*/
void logger_DEBUG(const std::string &pClass_function, const std::string &pMessage);
/**
 * Logger printed when the Log_level is 4 and higher
 * @param Message String that we want to print
*/
void logger_INFO(const std::string &pMessage);
/**
 * Logger printed when the Log_level is 3 and higher
 * @param Class_function String that represent the class::function
 * @param Message String that we want to print
*/
void logger_WARNING(const std::string &pClass_function, const std::string &pMessage);
/**
 * Logger printed when the Log_level is 2 and higher
 * @param Class_function String that represent the class::function
 * @param Message String that we want to print
*/
void logger_ERROR(const std::string &pClass_function, const std::string &pMessage);

/**
 * Getter of the Log_level
*/
int get_Log_level();

/**
 * Setter of the Log_level
 * @param pLog_level
*/
void set_Log_level(const int &pLog_level);

private:
std::string date_time();
};
```

logger.cpp :

```
#include "Logger.hpp"
#include <filesystem>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

Logger::Logger(int pLog_level, const std::string &pName_Log_File) : _Log_level(pLog_level)
{
    std::cout << "LOGGER created" << std::endl;
    if (pName_Log_File != "cmd")
    {
        std::filesystem::create_directory("LOG");
        std::string output_file = "./LOG/" + pName_Log_File + ".txt";

        std::freopen(const_cast<char *>(output_file.c_str()), "w", stdout);
    }
}

Logger::~Logger()
{
}
void Logger::logger_DEBUG(const std::string &pClass_function, const std::string &pMessage)
{
    if (this->_Log_level > 4)
    {
        std::cout << "[" << this->date_time() << "]"
                  << " | [DEBUG] | [" << pClass_function << "] : " << pMessage << std::endl;
    }
}

void Logger::logger_INFO(const std::string &pMessage)
{
    if (this->_Log_level > 3)
    {
        std::cout << "[" << this->date_time() << "]"
                  << " | [INFO] : " << pMessage << std::endl;
    }
}
void Logger::logger_WARNING(const std::string &pClass_function, const std::string &pMessage)
{
    if (this->_Log_level > 2)
    {
        std::cout << "[" << this->date_time() << "]"
                  << " | [WARNING] | [" << pClass_function << "] : " << pMessage << std::endl;
    }
}
void Logger::logger_ERROR(const std::string &pClass_function, const std::string &pMessage)
{
    if (this->_Log_level > 1)
    {
        std::cout << "[" << this->date_time() << "]"
                  << " | [ERROR] | [" << pClass_function << "] : " << pMessage << std::endl;
    }
}

int Logger::get_Log_level()
{
    return this->_Log_level;
}

void Logger::set_Log_level(const int &pLog_level)
{
    this->_Log_level = pLog_level;
}

std::string Logger::date_time()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::time_t time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(start);
    auto res = std::string(std::ctime(&time));
    res.pop_back();
    return res;
}
```

To reprensent in a better way the problem :
Commenting every line of the logger in my application valgrind :

`total heap usage: 312,852 allocs, 312,852 frees, 7,055,259 bytes allocated`

log_level is 0, nothing is printed but functions are called, valgrind :

`518,672 allocs, 518,672 frees, 23,963,961 bytes allocated`

log_level is 5, everything is printed, valgrind :

`total heap usage: 857,872 allocs, 857,872 frees, 30,917,557 bytes allocated`

Comment: My code uses this kind of pattern: `if (log(log::warning)) log << log::warning("MyFunction") << "rvalue is " << rvalue << log::endl;` which avoids incurring the overhead of the parameters in the path-less-traveled case.  (The actual implementation uses, *ick ick*, convenience **macros**:  `WARN("MyFunction", "rvalue is " << rvalue);`.)

Comment: @Eljay it seems to prevent the construction of the arguments with the only check of the log_level, i can admite it as a better solution than surrounding everything but `ifndef`, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better solution would be not to call the log function when the log level is under the threshold.

```
enum LEVEL {
    FATAL = 1,
    ERROR = 2,
    WARN = 3,
    INFO = 4,
    DEBUG = 5,
};

#define MLOG(logger, level, func, msg) \
do { \
    if (logger.get_Log_level() >= level) { \
        logger.logger_##level(func, msg); \
    } \
} while(0);

// logger.logger_INFO("", "");
MLOG(logger, INFO, "", "");
```

By the way, the logic of the logger for different levels in your code is almost the same and you can replace it with macro.

Comment: Thanks, but, is the arguments allocated in the heap at the macro's call `MLOG(logger, INFO, "", "");`, or at the function's call `logger.logger_##level(func, msg);`?
I'm not rly confident with macros *

Comment: @Clément No, there's no argument copy if no needed; the macro `MLOG` will be substituted by the code `do { ... } while(0);` in an early stage of the compilation, so, at runtime, you are only paying here for a `get_Log_level()` call and a check against `level` for every `logger_<LEVEL>` call.

Comment: so it's like implementing Eljay's solution but more transparent to the reading of the code?

Comment: @Clément Exactly. Actually, Eljay said in their comment that they use something like `if (logger.get_Log_level()...` but that, in the final implementation, they use convenience macros, like `MLOG...`.

Answer (score 1):

You could template your `Logger` class on the log level. That way:

- You would avoid parameter copies and level checks within your log methods.
- It could also let you adopt different strategies depending on the log level (e.g. some logs to file, some to console).
- On the other hand, you would end up having multiple instances of your `Logger` class (you could have one instance for each level of logging if you used singletons). That would make accesses to resources more complicated.
- And you wouldn't be able to change the log level on the fly, which, considering you have a `set_Log_level` method, may be a must for you (in that case, I would still think of a solution where I would have different logger instances for each level, and delegate to any of them depending on the current log level).

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/j6Eb8aWej)

NOTE: I made each template specialization inherit from the general one to try and reuse some common behaviour, but it looks quite awkward; so that part definitely needs a rethink.

```cpp
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <string>

template <int log_level_ = 4>
struct Logger {
    Logger(const std::string &pName_Log_File = "cmd")
    { std::cout << "Logger ctor\n"; }
    ~Logger()
    { std::cout << "Logger dtor\n"; }
    void log(const std::string &pClass_function, const std::string &pMessage)
    { std::cout << "[INFO]\n"; }
    int get_log_level()
    { return log_level_; }
};

template <>
struct Logger<5> : Logger<> {
    void log() { std::cout << "[DEBUG]\n"; }
};

template <>
struct Logger<3> : Logger<> {
    void log() { std::cout << "[WARNING]\n"; }
};

template <>
struct Logger<2> : Logger<> {
    void log() { std::cout << "[ERROR]\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    constexpr int ll_debug{5};
    constexpr int ll_info{4};
    constexpr int ll_warning{3};
    constexpr int ll_error{2};
    
    Logger<ll_debug> logger_debug{};
    logger_debug.log();

    Logger<ll_warning> logger_warning{};
    logger_warning.log();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, i actually have only one instance of my logger into a global variable in a namespace and using `extern` keyword to reach it, i set the log level depends of the greedy algorithm i'm using to not "over write".